# recv() function too slow

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, pygame

Hi i'm quite a newbie to Python. I' writting a simple LAN game (not simple for me) using a pygame module.

Here's the problem - I have two computers (one old intel Atom netbook, the other intel i5 NTB). I want to achieve at least 5 FPS (the netbook is slowering the NTB, but not so much, now i have around 1,5 FPS), but calling recv() function twice a main loop takes total around 0,5 seconds on each machine. The wifi signal is strong and the router is 300Mbit/s and it sends a short roughly 500-character string. As you can see for measuring time i use time.clock().

Here's the part of the "server" code, which i usually run on the i5 NTB:

```
while 1:
    start = time.clock()
    messagelen = c.recv(4)      #length of the following message (fixed 4 character)
    if " " in messagelen:
        messagelen = messagelen.replace(" ","")
    message = cPickle.loads(c.recv(int(messagelen))) #list of the arrows, other player position and changes in the game map
    arrowsmod = message[0]
    modtankposan = message[1]
    removelistmod = message[2]
    for i in removelistmod:
        try:
             randopos.remove(i)
        except ValueError:
            randopossv.remove(i)

    print time.clock()-start


    tosendlist=[]
    if len(arrows) == 0:  #if there are no arrows it appends only an empty list
        tosendlist.append([])
    else:
        tosendlist.append(arrows)
    tosendlist.append([zeltankpos, 360-angle])
    if len(removelist) == 0:   #if there are no changes of the map it appends only an empty list
        tosendlist.append([])
    else:
        tosendlist.append(removelist)
        removelist=[]
    tosend=cPickle.dumps(tosendlist)
    tosendlen = str(len(tosend))
    while len(tosendlen)<4:
        tosendlen+=" "
    c.sendall(tosendlen)   #sends the length to client
    c.sendall(tosend)      #sends the actual message(dumped list of lists) to client

    ...something else which takes <0,05 sec on the NTB
```

Here's the part of the "client" game code (just inverted the beginning - sending/receiving parts):

```
while 1:
    tosendlist=[]
    if len(arrows) == 0:  #if there are no arrows it appends only an empty list
        tosendlist.append([])
    else:
        tosendlist.append(arrows)
    tosendlist.append([zeltankpos, 360-angle])
    if len(removelist) == 0:   #if there are no changes of the map it appends only an empty list
        tosendlist.append([])
    else:
        tosendlist.append(removelist)
        removelist=[]
    tosend=cPickle.dumps(tosendlist)
    tosendlen = str(len(tosend))
    while len(tosendlen)<4:
        tosendlen+=" "
    s.sendall(tosendlen)   #sends the length to server
    s.sendall(tosend)      #sends the actual message(dumped list of lists) to server

    start = time.clock()
    messagelen = s.recv(4)      #length of the following message (fixed 4 character)
    if " " in messagelen:
        messagelen = messagelen.replace(" ","")
    message = cPickle.loads(s.recv(int(messagelen))) #list of the arrows, other player position and changes in the game map
    arrowsmod = message[0]
    modtankposan = message[1]
    removelistmod = message[2]
    for i in removelistmod:
        try:
             randopos.remove(i)
        except ValueError:
            randopossv.remove(i)

    print time.clock()-start
    ... rest which takes on the old netbook <0,17 sec
```

When I run let's say a single player version of the game on one machine (without the socket module) on the i5 NTB it has 50 FPS in the up left corner of the map and 25 FPS in the down right corner (the 1000x1000 pixel map contains 5x5 pixel squares, i think it's slower because of the bigger coordinates, but i can't believe that so much. BTW recv while ran as a LAN game in the down right corner of the map takes approx. the same time)
on the Atom netbook it has 4-8 FPS.

So could you please tell me, why it's so slow? The computers are not synchronized, one is faster, the other slower, but it can't be that they are waiting for each other, it would be max 0,17 secs delay, right? And plus the long recv calling would be only on the faster computer?
Also I don't exactly know how the send/recv function work. It's weird the sendall takes literally no time while receiving takes 0,5 secs. Maybe sendall 
is trying to send in the background while the rest of the program continues forward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by Armin Rigo, `recv` will return after packets are received by the socket, but packets don't necessarily need to be transmitted immediately after calling `send`. While `send` returns immediately, OS caches the data internally and might wait some time for more data being written to the the socket before actually transmitting it; this is called [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) and avoids sending lots of small packets over the network. You can disable it and push packets quicker to the wire; try enabling `TCP_NODELAY` options on the *sending* socket (or both if your communication is bidirectional), by calling this:

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
```

This could potentially reduce amount of time `recv` is sleeping due to no data.

As the Wikipedia states:

> This algorithm interacts badly with TCP delayed acknowledgments, a
>   feature introduced into TCP at roughly the same time in the early
>   1980s, but by a different group. With both algorithms enabled,
>   applications that do two successive writes to a TCP connection,
>   followed by a read that will not be fulfilled until after the data
>   from the second write has reached the destination, experience a
>   constant delay of up to **500 milliseconds**, the "ACK delay". For this
>   reason, TCP implementations usually provide applications with an
>   interface to disable the Nagle algorithm. This is typically called the
>   TCP_NODELAY option.

There is a mention of 0.5s which you're seeing in your benchmark, so this might be a reason.

Comment: Nagle's algorithm doesn't affect the timing of send(). send() just writes to the socket send buffer and then returns. All the actual writing to the wire, packet coalescing, etc., takes place asynchronously to the application and won't be measured by a timer.

Comment: @EJP you're correct, my wording wasn't very careful here – there is no delay in `send` function per se, but the delay associated with kernel pushing the data to the wire (and here Nagle's algorithm) can be visible on `recv` side and could affect the timer there.

Comment: Also note that he has timers around `recv` and not `send`. I don't know if this is Nagle's fault, but think odds are high enough to give it a shot and experiment a little bit around this subject.

Comment: It's what you're saying! I set NODELAY and the recv time is usually <0,15 secs, sometimes 0,06 secs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, send() or sendall() will occur in the background (unless the connexion is saturated right now, i.e. there is already too much data waiting to be sent).  By contrast, recv() will immediately get the data only if it arrived already, but if none did, it waits.  Then it returns possibly a fraction of it.  (I am assuming that c is a TCP socket, not a UDP one.)  Note that you should not assume that recv(N) returns N bytes; you should write a function like this:

```
def recvall(c, n):
    data = []
    while n > 0:
        s = c.recv(n)
        if not s: raise EOFError
        data.append(s)
        n -= len(s)
    return ''.join(data)
```

Anyway, to the point.  The issue is not the speed of recv().  If I understood correctly, there are four operations:

- the server renders (1/25th sec)
- the server sends something on the socket, received by the client;
- the client renters (1/4th sec);
- the client send something back on the socket.

This takes almost `(0.3 + 2 * network_delay)` seconds.  Nothing occurs in parallel.  If you want more frames-per-second, you need to parallelize some of these four operations.  For example, let's assume reasonably that the operation 3 is by far the slowest.  Here's how we can make 3 run in parallel with the three other operations.  You should change the client so that it receives data, process it, and immediately sends an answer to the server; and only then it proceeds to render it.  This should be enough in this case, as it takes 1/4th seconds to do this rendering, which should be enough time for the answer to reach the server, the server to render, and the next packet to be sent again.

Comment: Would the ideal method be to use one thread for networking, and the other for the main game loop?

Comment: No, no, the 4 operations I describe occur at different physical locations: you don't need threads.

Comment: Thanks for the recvall tip. You mean that 1 byte of buff size is not always one character? But for now it works, otherwise there would be a pickle error. Also I forgot to mention that when I did an experiment and separated these lines of code from the game (+- the same code i posted but with a sample to-send-list)and I ran them there's no such delay. The two recv calls take 0,1 or 0,01 secs I don't exactly remember but for sure it's a lot less than 0,5 - also @tomasz. That's strange. Sorry but I didn't get the parallel instructions. how do I do it?

Comment: Now the communication is bidirectional, client and server are almost the same programs but first the client sends the data and server receives then server sends the data and client receives. (It could be reversed but it's not crucial is it?)Then both programs "render" the graphics and do the game processing. Then it repeats. (The data length receive and data receive take total 0,5 secs on each machine) So could you please explain it again I'm quite a noob

Comment: Draw a diagram if needed: it should indeed be reversed.  About 1 byte == 1 character: read the doc of socket.recv() to learn more: recv(N) can return a random amount of data up to N bytes.

Comment: Ok I inverted it and the results are finally rational; the two recv calls finally take on the client (slow netbook) approx 3,5 secs (not 0,5 secs as before) and the two recv calls on the server take more or less 0,5 secs, that's the time of one client main loop repetiton, so now it a little more makes sense. 
I may say it's rational, but still it's not reasonable. I mean 2 FPS is not sufficent. Thanks for the hint inverting it, but i don't know why it works:(, but the main think is it works. When I said in the previous comments I made an experiment, i made a mistake. That experiment wasn't

Comment: bidirectional, it was only that server sends client receives, now i made bidirectional and recv calling is a little longer than with the game code, approx 0.4-0.6 secs! Also as I once said when the game loop is dealing with bigger coordinates, the loop gets slower, and the recv, even when receiving bigger numbers gets faster! So it may be the thing tomasz and wikipedia say - about 500 ms delay or not?

Comment: Yes it is the 500 ms delay too. Nevertheless thanks alot, but still i don't know how the inversion of server client send recv sequence hepled, but helped.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here when having same issue with it appearing that socket recv in python to be super slow.  The fix for me (after days) was to do something along the lines:

```
  recv_buffer = 2048 # ? guess & check
  ...
  rx_buffer_temp = self._socket.recv(recv_buffer)
  rx_buffer_temp_length = len(rx_buffer_temp)
  recv_buffer = max(recv_buffer, rx_buffer_temp_length)  # keep to the max needed/found
```

The gist of it is set to the amount of bytes trying to receive closest to the actual expected.