# Improve PyMongo socket recv

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, pymongo-3.x

I have done some profiling in my code (using PyMongo 3.0.3 with a lot of bulk operations) with cProfile and it turns out that a lot of time is spent on sockets:

`14006   68.823    0.005   68.823    0.005 {method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}`

I have found this [somewhat related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741196/recv-function-too-slow) and the solution is simple. Is there any way to pass the `TCP_NOWAIT` option to `PyMongo` without having to change the libs code?

Comment: hey, did you figure out anything on this? Running into the same issue, would greatly appreciate an update on your findings.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I haven't. I'm actually not working on the project anymore, but what I had found at that time is that PyMongo apparently has its own implementation of the sockets. There were even comments on the claiming that the standard socket related functions couldn't be used for some reason.

Comment: ok, thanks for getting back, if I find a relevant solution, i'll add it here.

Comment: I have started a bounty. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can monkey patch socket...

```
#before you import or do anything...
import socket
socket.raw_socket = socket.socket

def my_socket(*args, **kws):
    sock = socket.socket(*args, **kws)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    return sock

socket.socket = my_socket
#cross fingers ...
```